# Binary search tree recursive insert

Tags: java, recursion, insert, tree

We were given the Node class and we have to implement the recursive insertion. After the insertion my output is wrong and I don't know why

The function printTree was given:

```
public void printTree() {
    printTree(root,0);
     }

public  void printTree(TreeNode<T> p, int depth) {
    if (p != null) {
        if (!(p.left == null && p.right == null))
            printTree(p.right,depth+1);
        for (int i = 1; i <= depth; i++)
             System.out.print("   ");
        if (p.left == null && p.right == null)
             System.out.println(p.info + " ");
        else System.out.println(p.info);
        printTree(p.left,depth+1);
    }
}
```

This is my insertion function:

```
public void insert(T info)
{
    root = insert(root, info);
}

protected TreeNode<T> insert(TreeNode<T> node, T info)
{
             if (node == null)
             {
                node = new TreeNode<T>(info);
             }

              else if (info.compareTo(node.info) < 0)
              {
                node.left  = insert(node.left,info);
              }

           else 
           {
            node.right = insert(node.right,info);
           }
           return node;
      }
```

This is my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Tree<Integer> t = new Tree<Integer>();

    t.insert(4);
    t.insert(3);
    t.insert(5);
    t.insert(1);
    t.printTree();
}
```

and the output I get is:

```
  5 
4
  3
    1
```

instead of:

```
  4
 3 5
1
```

Comment: The `printTree()` function that was given to you prints the tree upside down. What gave it away was the indentation on the 3. It's correctly indented, but on the wrong line.

Comment: Try inserting several more numbers and see what output you get. It may be that it's just printing wrong.

Comment: I tried more inputs...and as you can see everything is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output seems ok to me.

The `printTree` method does not work as you expect. It prints the tree from top to bottom level, but on the screen the output is "rotated" by 90 deg
So the top level is meant to be on the first column, bottom level at the last non-empty column.

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean. Thank you